# ¿Cómo Enviar los datos de una fila al controlador?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Mi idea es la siguiente, al hacer click en Editar quiero mandar al controlador solo los datos de ese libro en particular, de la manera que lo estoy haciendo me envía al controlador todos los datos de todos los libros que figuran ahi, como podría hacer? Estoy usando `@using (Html.BeginForm("EditarLibro", "Home", FormMethod.Post))`y adentro de este formulario utilizo un foreach para que me vaya mostrando cada uno de los libros en un `<tr>`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditarLibro", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-primary mt-5 border-primary" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Autor</th>
                    <th>Descripcion</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @if (Model.Count() == 0)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" style="color:red">
                            No Match any document
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

                else
                {
                    foreach (Libro item in Model)
                    {


                        autor = sa.getAutor(item.IdAutor);
                        editorial = es.GetEditorial(item.IdEditorial);
                        category = cs.getCategoria(item.IdCategoria);
                        
                        <tr>

                            <input id="idBook" name="idBook" type="hidden" value="@item.IdLibro">
                            <input id="rutaImg" name="rutaImg" type="hidden" value="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")">
                            <th>
                                <input type="submit" name="btn_mostrar" value="mostrar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                <input type="submit" name="btn_editar" value="Editar" class="btn btn-warning" />
                                <input type="submit" name="btn_baja" value="Baja" class="btn btn-daner" />
                            </th>
                            <th><input type="text" id="lbl_bookName" name="lbl_bookName" value="@item.Nombre"></input></th>
                            <th><input type="text" id="lbl_autorName" name="lbl_autorName" value="@autor.Nombre"></input></th>
                            <th class="col-md-3"><input type="text" id="lbl_description" name="lbl_description" value="@item.Descripcion"></input></th>
                            <th><input type="text" id="lbl_price" name="lbl_price" value="@item.Precio"></input></th>
                            <th><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
                        </tr>
                        
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Aca el HomeController

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditarLibro(FormCollection form)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        if(form["btn_Editar"] != null)
        { 
        var idBook = form["idBook"];
        var bookName = form["lbl_bookName"];
        var autorName = form["lbl_autorName"];
        var description = form["lbl_description"];
        var price = form["lbl_price"];
        var rutaImg = form["rutaImg"];
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Podrías incluir el código que utilizas para enviar los datos al controlador? y el controlador mismo también :)

Comment: Gracias @Paulo Urbano Rivera ahí publique el código!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo normalmente lo que hago es enviar el id (en este caso el id del libro o la forma en que tengas para identificarlo) utilizando @Html.ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink(
"Editar",                                                  // texto
"EditarLibro",                                    // nombre de la accion
"Controller",                                                   // Nombre del controlador
new {                                                     // routeValues
    idLibro = item.Id},
null                                                      // htmlAttributes
```

)

Y el controlador lo dejaria

```
public ActionResult EditarLibro(int idLibro)
{
   //Aca haria un metodo para obtener un libro por Id
   //Y todo lo que necesites hacer cuando lo obtengas
}
```

Y en la vista

```
foreach (Libro item in Model)
                {


                    autor = sa.getAutor(item.IdAutor);
                    editorial = es.GetEditorial(item.IdEditorial);
                    category = cs.getCategoria(item.IdCategoria);

                    <tr>

                        <input id="idBook" name="idBook" type="hidden" value="@item.IdLibro">
                        <input id="rutaImg" name="rutaImg" type="hidden" value="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")">
                        <th>
                            <input type="submit" name="btn_mostrar" value="mostrar" class="btn btn-primary" />                              
                     @Html.ActionLink("Editar","EditarLibro","Controller",new { idLibro =item.Id}, null)
                            <input type="submit" name="btn_baja" value="Baja" class="btn btn-daner" />
                        </th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="lbl_bookName" name="lbl_bookName" value="@item.Nombre"></input></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="lbl_autorName" name="lbl_autorName" value="@autor.Nombre"></input></th>
                        <th class="col-md-3"><input type="text" id="lbl_description" name="lbl_description" value="@item.Descripcion"></input></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="lbl_price" name="lbl_price" value="@item.Precio"></input></th>
                        <th><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>
                    </tr>

                }
```

En el Html ActionLink podrias pasar todos los datos del libro tambien, pero a mi no me gusta hacer eso de esa manera, prefiero enviar solo el id al controller y que este se encargue de buscarlo con un metodo

Comment: Gracias ahora funciona! me había olvidado de sacar el [HttpPost] del HomeController como asi tmb @using (Html.BeginForm("EditarLibro", "Home", FormMethod.Post) del .cshtml .

Comment: @Claudio si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como correcta :)

Comment: Ahi lo hice muchas gracias @Paulo Urbano Rivera !!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido. Un saludo